# Kommasetzung "Künstler ebenso wie eine Geschäftsfrau oder Eltern brauchen, Kreativität bei ihrer täglichen Arbeit."

Tags: punctuation

In einem Lehrwerk gibt es eine Aufgabe zur Korrektur der Kommasetzung. Folgender Satz:

> Künstler ebenso wie eine Geschäftsfrau oder Eltern brauchen,
> Kreativität bei ihrer täglichen Arbeit.

Das Komma nach dem Verb *brauchen* ist eindeutig falsch. Aber in den Lösungen steht:

> Künstler ebenso wie eine Geschäftsfrau oder Eltern **(kein Komma)**
> brauchen Kreativität bei ihrer täglichen Arbeit.

Also VOR dem Verb.

Zwei Fragen:

1. Könnte man den Teil *ebenso wie eine Geschäftsfrau oder Eltern* etwa nicht als Apposition betrachten und durch Kommata trennen?
2. Wenn man die Wortfolge etwas umstellt, - *Künstler brauchen Kreativität bei ihrer täglichen Arbeit ebenso wie eine Geschäftsfrau oder Eltern* - könnte man ein Komma nach *Arbeit* setzen?

Comment: Ich frage mich, wieso die Geschäftsfrau hier in Einzahl steht, während Künstler und Eltern in Mehrzahl stehen. Statt "oder" müsste es m.E. auch "und" heißen. Ich schätze das "ebenso" vertritt das Komma, so dass man entweder Komma setzt oder "ebenso" gebraucht, ähnlich wie auch "und" und "oder" ein Komma ersetzen, bzw. umgekehrt, das Komma diese.

Comment: Die Umstellung ist keine gute Idee; in Beispiel zwei ist nicht mehr klar, ob Geschäftsfrau und Eltern eine Aufzählung mit Künstler bildet (damit Nominativ-Subjekt), oder eine mit Kreativität (Akkusativ-Objekt).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - Künstler ebenso wie eine Geschäftsfrau oder Eltern brauchen Kreativität bei ihrer täglichen Arbeit.
> - Künstler, ebenso wie eine Geschäftsfrau oder Eltern, brauchen Kreativität bei ihrer täglichen Arbeit.
> - Künstler brauchen Kreativität bei ihrer täglichen Arbeit, ebenso wie eine Geschäftsfrau oder Eltern.

sind allesamt erlaubt gem. [§ 78](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6201#par78) des amtlichen Regelwerks:

> Oft liegt es im Ermessen des Schreibenden, ob er etwas mit Komma als Zusatz oder Nachtrag kennzeichnen will oder nicht.

Das Beispiel fällt unter [Absatz 3](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6201#par78-3): *Infinitiv-, Partizip- oder Adjektivgruppen **oder entsprechende Wortgruppen***.

Comment: I might say “Künstler brauchen ebenso wie eine Geschäftsfrau oder Eltern Kreativität bei ihrer täglichen Arbeit.” This emphasises the similarity between people, while yours emphasises the need for creativity.